# Proftpd can't retrieve directory listing when outside the network

Tags: server, ftp, xampp, proftpd

I know this question has been asked many times on the internet and a google search will bring up a multitude of posts, but none of them have been of any help and are all very vague and not specific, so I aim to finally get a definite answer out there on the internet.

Basically I have ubuntu running proftpd as part of the xampp package. Connections inside the network are fine. 
Clients *inside* the network can establish a connection to the server, authenticate themselves and retrieve directory listings and all that jazz.

Clients *outside* the network can establish a connection, authenticate themselves but get stuck at `Retrieving Directory Listing...` and times out.

```
Status:     Connecting to ***.***.***.***:21...
Status:     Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status:     Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status:     Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status:     Connected
Status:     Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (165,228,195,88,240,255).
Command:    MLSD
Error:      The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out
Error:      Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:      Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I am aware this has something to do with an Active vs Passive form of connection. I can't figure out which one I want or how to make it work.

Previously, I had an FTP server running on Windows using FileZilla Server. I ran into this same passive/active problem and was able to solve it using *a single port*. Many other solutions on the internet have been setting to passive mode and forwarding a bunch if ports (ie. 60000-65534) but considering in the past I was able to make it work with just 21 as the incoming connection, I should be able to do it again.

My proftpd.conf file is slapped on over here --> [pastebin.com/YSgKw1Jk](http://pastebin.com/YSgKw1Jk)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance!